# Download files with BitTransfer not working

Tags: powershell

I am trying to download a file via BitsTransfer.
The download works fine in my browser, however it doesn't even attempt to connect to the server by using

`Start-BitsTransfer "https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/E/C/4EC66C83-1E15-43FD-B591-63FB7A14/Windows8.1-KB2919355-x86.msu" \Users\Admin\testfilekb -Asynchronous`

(checked that with Wireshark)

I m using Powershell the first day, so I am not familiar with any possible prerequisites for this to work.

I tried different servers/file types, it always shows an error like this:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> Get-BitsTransfer


    JobId                   DisplayName             TransferType            JobState                OwnerAccount
    -----                   -----------             ------------            --------                ------------
    8615331f-0ed2-4688-9... BITS Transfer           Download                Error                   Admin-PC\Admin
```

Comment: The Destination path seems incomplete. Use an absolute path to an existing folder

Comment: I tried `Start-BitsTransfer "https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/E/C/4EC66C83-1E15-43FD-B591-63FB7A14/Windows8.1-KB2919355-x86.msu" C:\Users\Admin\newfolder -Asynchronous`
and now a file was created inside that folder, however its .tmp and has 0KB.
Get-BitsTransfer still displays it as error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused as the web server returns 404 not found. Try the URL with a browser. I tried and got a 404 too. It seems that the URL isn't right.

To get the actual error code, use `Get-BitsTransfer` (output is trimmed a bit) and convert `InternalErrorCode` as a hex value for googling:

```
PS C:\> Get-BitsTransfer
JobId                                DisplayName   TransferType JobState 
-----                                -----------   ------------ -------- 
76298096-31f2-4882-80e5-a8391fadaf92 BITS Transfer Download     Error    


PS C:\> $bt =Get-BitsTransfer -JobId 76298096-31f2-4882-80e5-a8391fadaf92
PS C:\> $bt.InternalErrorCode
-2145844844
```

Convert the integer as a hex value like so,

```
([int]-2145844844).tostring('x')
80190194
```

And refer to Bits source code. The header [BitsMsg.h](https://github.com/nihon-tc/LFMtest/blob/master/header/Microsoft%20SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Include/BitsMsg.h) explains that it's 404 not found:

```
// MessageId: BG_E_HTTP_ERROR_404
// MessageText:
// HTTP status 404: The requested URL does not exist on the server.
#define BG_E_HTTP_ERROR_404              0x80190194L
```